# VHDL assignment slice not implemented?

Tags: vhdl, slice

Is it possible to specify a bit range to be assigned on the left side of the assignment?

eg. `R(15 downto 8) <= R(15 downto 8) -D;`

The above gives me the compiler error: `Error 722: Assignment to a signal slice is not implemented.` I've tried Googling the error to no avail.

However this works:

`R <= R(15 downto 8) - D;`

Comment: Perhaps you'd be willing to tell us which (who's) analyzer is telling you this?  A slice name is legal as a target of a signal assignment statement in VHDL.  The format looks like that of the PICA VHDL tool, wherein the 722 would represent a line number.

Comment: Apologies for leaving out my environment details. Using DesignWorks Professional 5 on Windows 7.

The 722 is the error code. The line number was expressed separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer pertains to my environment, specifically DesignWorks Professional 5, on Windows 7.

You **cannot** assign values to a slice of a **signal variable** bit vector.
eg.

```
signal R: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
R(15 downto 0) <= X"0000"; -- will not compile
```

You **can** assign values to a slice of a an **ordinary variable** bit vector.
eg.

```
variable D: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
D(15 downto 0) := X"0000"; -- will compile
```

Each case attempts to assign 16 bits to a 16 bit variable.

Comment: If that second one compiles, and the first does not, I strongly urge you to get a better synthesis tool. The first should compile, and the second should only compile if you use `D(15 downto 0) := X"00";`.

Comment: Maybe the first one does not compile because you are assigning an 8 bit vector X"00" to a 16 bit signal.  Try:
R(15 downto 0) <= X"0000";  That should absolutely compile.  And zennehoy is correct, when assigning variables use the := assignment rather than <=.

Comment: @Russell: You're right about the vector size. It was incorrect in my above answer, it's correct in my code. Edited now.

Comment: @zennehoy: I wish I could, unfortunately I'm stuck with this compiler (reasons withheld). Also you're correct about my incorrect ordinary variable assignment, it should have been ":=" instead of "<=". It's edited now, but still doesn't compile.

Comment: @cbrad This is almost certainly a tool issue - it apparently doesn't fully implement the VHDL standard. If you're stuck using that tool, I'm afraid you'll have to work around the problem in some other way. For example, you could create two signals for the upper and lower parts of R, then assign to R at the architecture level: `R <= R_top & R_bot;`

Comment: @zennehoy: I agree, with it being a tool issue, and also with the work around. I will add my implementation of the work around to my answer soon.

Comment: Maybe you are not showing us enough of the code.  Do you get this error when the assignment to the signal is the only thing in the architecture?  What is the error when you use the signal?  Did you put the signal assignment in the same process as the variable assignment that does work.

Comment: When I get a chance I'll post the code... but I'm convinced it's just the compiler I was using.

Answer (score 1):

Assignments to slices are allowed.  What tool are you using?  What is the size of D?  Pay attention to result sizes.  If the size of D is larger than R, then the result size matches the size of D.

What happens in the following assignments:

```
R(15 downto 0) <= R(15 downto 8) - D ;
```

If this assignment works, then you need to also slice D:

```
R(15 downto 8) <= R(15 downto 8) - D(7 downto 0);
```

If this does not get it, what does the rest of the code look like?

Comment: I'm using DesignWorks Professional 5. It's not a size issue. I should have mentioned that the assignment is on a signal variable, not an ordinary variable, which is apparently illegal.